# convert line-separated values into a syntax

Tags: linux, bash, perl, unix

I have been given a text file it contains many, many values all of which are separated one line at at a time, as follows. EX:

```
blue
red
orange
green
colors
hopefully
you
get
the
idea
```

I am pretty familiar with the command line, and want to learn something new today.

I have to take these values and insert them in a syntax, the syntax will be the same for each value.

example:

```
<a href="blue">
<a href="red">
<a href="orange">
<a href="green">
<a href="colors">
```

and so on.

something tells me that copy paste is the not only working solution to this problem, nor the most efficient.

any thought on this?

Thanks for reading.

Comment: Use awk. As an aside, I hope you're closing those `<a>` tags somewhere else!

Comment: yeah, there not colors nor going in an `<a>` tag i just wanted to ask a simple question, that i could then apply to my situation specifically

Comment: What are you actually trying to accomplish? This looks a bit like an XY problem, because you're _not_ generating valid HTML there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

awk can do this pretty easily. Note: you should be closing your  tags:

```
$ awk '{ print "<a href=\""$1"\"></a>" }' file 
<a href="blue"></a>
<a href="red"></a>
<a href="orange"></a>
<a href="green"></a>
<a href="colors"></a>
<a href="hopefully"></a>
<a href="you"></a>
<a href="get"></a>
<a href="the"></a>
<a href="idea"></a>
```

Comment: Thanks! i just learned grep the other day too. really appreciate that.

Answer (score 2):

With `sed`, you can refer to the unique match with `&`:

```
$ sed 's/.*/<a href="&">/' file
<a href="blue">
<a href="red">
<a href="orange">
<a href="green">
...
```

Then, it is a matter of adding the desired text around `&`.

Answer (score 1):

If you are just trying to do this particular example, you can simply prepend and append chars to each line:

```
sed -i -e 's/^/<a href="/' -e 's/$/">/' yourfile
```

Comment: `sed -i -e 's/^.*$/<a href="&">/'` would be simpler. Just specify the entire replacement string with the matched text (`&`) embedded in it.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this:

```
#!/bin/bash 
while IFS= read line; do
line="<a href=\"$line\">"
echo "$line"
done <file.txt
```

If you want to redirect the output to a separate file, then:
change:

```
echo "$line"
```

to:

```
echo "$line" >> separate_file.txt
```

or even better:
change

```
echo "$line"
done <file.txt
```

to:

```
echo "$line" # This is necessary and it won't print output 
done <file.txt > separate_file.txt
```

Comment: As attractive as it may seem to go with a "shell-only" solution, I would strongly recommend using a text-processing tool such as awk or sed whenever it comes to processing some text :)

Comment: If you want to redirect the output to a separate file, you're better off using `done < file.txt > separate_file.txt`, rather than appending to the file each iteration of the loop.

Comment: thnks, @TomFenech, added your suggestion

Answer (score 1):

To take your example, and because there isn't a perl answer yet - as [Tom](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2088135/tom-fenech) points out:

"Surely the perl answer may as well just be a straight port of the awk answer `perl -lne 'print "<a href=\"$_\">"' file`, or of the sed answer `perl -pe 's/(.*)/<a href="$1">/' file"`. 
This is true - perl can 'one liner' and pretend to be one of the others.

But in a script, I might do:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $prefix = q{<A HREF="};
my $suffix = q{">};

while ( my $line = <DATA> ) {
   chomp ($line);
   print "$prefix$line$suffix\n";
}


__DATA__
blue
red
orange
green
colors
hopefully
you
get
the
idea
```

I would ask exactly what you're trying to accomplish though - this doesn't generate valid HTML, so I suspect you're looking at a different problem.

Just for the sake of variety though - you can probably pretend you're assembling XML here:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use XML::Twig;

my $xml = XML::Twig -> new( 'pretty_print' => 'indented' ); 
$xml -> set_root ( XML::Twig::Elt -> new ( 'HTML' ) );

while ( my $line = <DATA> ) {
   chomp ($line);
   $xml -> root -> insert_new_elt('last_child', "A", { "HREF" => $line }, "link to $line" );
}
$xml -> print;


__DATA__
blue
red
orange
green
colors
hopefully
you
get
the
idea
```

This will generate you:

```
<HTML>
  <A HREF="blue">link to blue</A>
  <A HREF="red">link to red</A>
  <A HREF="orange">link to orange</A>
  <A HREF="green">link to green</A>
  <A HREF="colors">link to colors</A>
  <A HREF="hopefully">link to hopefully</A>
  <A HREF="you">link to you</A>
  <A HREF="get">link to get</A>
  <A HREF="the">link to the</A>
  <A HREF="idea">link to idea</A>
</HTML>
```

This is - in my opinion - a better example of 'assembling a syntax' since it is better to follow formal/stricter definitions - like XML. (or JSON). These are particularly useful because they've got specifications that can be parsed, and so it's a lot easier to make inter operable, rather than using a bespoke file/data format.

Comment: Surely the perl answer may as well just be a straight port of the awk answer `perl -lne 'print "<a href=\"$_\">"' file`, or of the sed answer `perl -pe 's/(.*)/<a href="$1">/' file`.

Comment: You could do that, certainly. But then you'd not get a particularly different example. I was hoping to illustrate a different approach that the supplicant might find a useful alternative, rather than repeat what has been said already with slightly different flags. (Although I do like how you can pretty much 'do' `awk` or `sed` in perl)

Comment: I guess that it's nice to show the one-line approach as well, since it promotes the fact that perl is just as capable of getting the job done without requiring a full-blown script, although I do agree that it's nice to show some variety.

Answer (score 1):

A Perl solution:

```
perl -lpe'$_ = qq{<a href="$_">}' colors.txt
```

or

```
perl -le'print qq{<a href="$_">}' colors.txt
```